# Strange long time evaluation of Series for fractional function

Tags: series-expansion

my problem concerns the Series command applied to a product of a rational function times a square root. This can be exemplified in the following way

```
AA0[q_] := (3/(16  q^5) - 1/(4 q^3) + 1/q)
a0p2[rr_] := (AA0[q[rr]] Sqrt[1 + rr^2 D[q[rr], rr]^2])/(2 Sqrt[1 + rr^4 + AA0[q[rr]]^2])
q[rr_] := rr^-4 (q0 + q1 rr^(1/3))

NUM[rr_] := rr^2 D[q[rr], rr] Sqrt[bb^2 + rr^4]
DEN[rr_] := Sqrt[1 + rr^2 D[q[rr], rr]^2 - a0p2[rr]^2]
Series[NUM[rr]/DEN[rr], {rr, 0, 4}]
Clear[q]
```

Even if the series of NUM[rr] or 1/DEN[rr] is pretty fast, the function NUM/DEN is taking forever (and it has problem in aborting). Do you know a way to speed up the computation?

Of course, I can do the series separately and then merging them, but I do not want to use this trick.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try replacing `D[q[rr], rr]` with `q'[rr]` in your definitions and report back.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply. I tried as you suggested but the situation is unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Added approach using a series of ratio of series of `NUM` and `DEN`

```
AA0[q_] = (3/(16 q^5) - 1/(4 q^3) + 1/q) // Simplify;

q[rr_] = rr^-4 (q0 + q1 rr^(1/3));

a0p2[rr_] = (AA0[q[rr]] Sqrt[1 + rr^2 D[q[rr], rr]^2])/(2 Sqrt[
       1 + rr^4 + AA0[q[rr]]^2]) // Simplify;

NUM[rr_] = rr^2 D[q[rr], rr] Sqrt[bb^2 + rr^4] // Simplify;

DEN[rr_] = Sqrt[1 + rr^2 D[q[rr], rr]^2 - a0p2[rr]^2];
```

Expand the numerator and the denominator into separate series, then form the series from the quotient of these series.

```
soln = Timing[
  Series[(Series[NUM[rr], {rr, 0, 4}] // 
      Normal)/(Series[DEN[rr], {rr, 0, 4}] // Normal), {rr, 0, 4}]]
```

[image]

Comparing to the original approach

```
Timing[Series[NUM[rr]/DEN[rr], {rr, 0, 4}]]
```

[image]

I don't know that this will always give the same expression, but it does in this case.

The solution simplifies if `bb` and `q0` are real

```
soln[[-1]] // Simplify[#, Element[{bb, q0}, Reals]] &
```

[image]

```
% /. Abs[q0] -> Sign[q0]*q0
```

[image]

This simplifies more if `bb` and `q0` are nonnegative

```
soln[[-1]] // Simplify[#, {bb >= 0, q0 >= 0}] &
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to revive this post, I tried again the code you suggested and it's taking forever to evaluate. Probably when I checked the code on 15 May I probably made some mistake, that's why it was so fast. Now the situation is unchanged. Do you have any more idea?

Comment: Having calculated this once why do you need to ever recalculate this? Define the result as (or simpler form if any assumptions apply) :

`approx[bb_, q0_, rr_] = -Sqrt[bb^2] Sqrt[q0^2] rr/q0;`

Comment out the original evaluation and results so that you have a record of how you arrived at `approx`.

Comment: Hi, of course what I presented is just a simpler version of my full problem. I have to run it multiple time since I always have to tune some parameters and modify some pieces of the original formula. Anyhow, as i said before the presented piece of code modified thanks to your help is taking too much to evaluate. Do you have any other suggestions? In your pc the evaluation is fast? Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.